# Código JavaScript me ejecuta correctamente en mi IDE pero al pasarlo a la página de evaluación me da error

Tags: javascript, array

Debo encontrar en una matriz un valor par si los demás son impares e impar si los demás son pares. Me corre en mi IDE pero en la página de evaluación me da error, resalto que sólo uno de los valores debe ser par o impar y el resto debe ser contrario a ese único valor.

```
    var integers = [0, 1, 2];
    //var integers = [2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36];
    //var integers = [160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21];
    
    findOutlier(integers);
    
    
    function findOutlier(integers){
      var impar = 0;
      var par = 0;
      var contaPar = 0;
      var contaImpar = 0;
      
        for (let i = 0; i < integers.length; i++){
            
            divi = parseInt((integers[i] % 2));
            
            if(divi == 0){
                contaPar +=1;
                par = parseInt(integers[i]);
                
                
            }else{
                contaImpar +=1;
                impar = parseInt(integers[i]);
                
            }
        }
        
        if(contaPar > contaImpar){
            return console.log('El número diferente es impar: ' + impar);
        }else{
            return console.log('El número diferente es par: ' + par);
        }
    
    }
```

Les paso un pantallazo de la página de evaluación.[image: Pantallazo dónde me aparece con error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El fallo es que tu función no devuelve nada:

```
return console.log('El número diferente es impar: ' + impar);
```

debería ser:

```
console.log('El número diferente es impar: ' + impar);
return impar;
```

porque la llamada a `console.log` no devuelve nada

Comment: Le hice así y nada, en la imagen que compartí aparece el cambio realizado con el return, me da el mismo mensaje.